# (nx(gradxn))^2 operator question?

Tags: operator-theory, vector-analysis, operator-algebras

by $A\times B \times C = (A \cdot C)B-(A \cdot B)C$, i need to expand $n \times \bigtriangledown \times n$, where all of these are vectors.

Here is what i have right now

$n \times \bigtriangledown \times n = (n \cdot n) \bigtriangledown- (n \cdot \bigtriangledown) n$

I don't know how operator algebra works in order of operation, so i'm assuming right now this means

$\bigtriangledown (||n||^2)- n(\bigtriangledown \cdot n)$

Is this correct? This is part of a huge problem, i'm just trying to make sure how operators work in these operations

Ok, i recently edited, the problem i'm trying to solve is $(n \times \bigtriangledown \times n)^2$, maybe i will post the exact equations in another question.. This equation does not operate on anything, it becomes a scalar when squared

Comment: By "squaring it" do you mean dot product with itself? It would still operate on something because of the $\bigtriangledown$ in it.

Comment: Here is the specific equation i'm solving http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813131/nxgradxn2-specific-equation

Comment: Maybe this particular question should be closed, as it seems the OP has included more specifically the goal in the later question referred to in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Cross product not associative, so you need to parenthesize as $$A \times (B \times C)=(A\cdot C)B -(A\cdot B)C.$$
Note that the "multiplications" on the right are scalar multiplications, since each of $A \cdot C$ and $A \cdot B$ are scalars.

The operator $\bigtriangledown$ makes sense only (in your three dimensional case) when applied to a function $f(x,y,z)$ of three variables, and then $\bigtriangledown f$ is the vector $(f_x,f_y,f_z)$ of the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the variables $x,y,z$ (in that order).

So if you are considering $n \times (\bigtriangledown \times n),$ it could be interpreted as another operator, which can be computed by the formula you suggest but without the extra step. Namely you can say 
$$[n \times (\bigtriangledown \times n)](f)=(n \cdot n)\bigtriangledown f -(n \cdot \bigtriangledown f) n,$$
but the initial "factor" $n \cdot n$ here remains as a scalar multiplier to the evaluated operator $\bigtriangledown f,$ which is a vector valued function of three variables. As mentioned above the latter is a vector of partials of the given function $f$ of three variables which the whole expression is acting on. The second scalar factor $u \cdot \bigtriangledown f$ would be then also a scalar function of the three variables $x,y,z$ since $ \bigtriangledown f$ is a 3-vector and $n$ is also.